# Converting DateTime to unix timestamp and back again - result is not equal

Tags: c#, datetime, equality

I recently started learning C# and ran into a bug, I tracked it down and discovered it was because if I convert a `DateTime` object to a timestamp, then back to a `DateTime` object, the resulting `DateTime` doesn't equal the original one, even though to me they seem identical.

I put together a snippet to exhibit what I mean

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime ePoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan timeSpan = (dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - ePoch);
    double unixTimeStamp = timeSpan.TotalSeconds;

    DateTime dateTimeConvertedBack = ePoch.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);

    System.Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    System.Console.WriteLine(dateTimeConvertedBack);
    System.Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Millisecond);
    System.Console.WriteLine(dateTimeConvertedBack.Millisecond);
    System.Console.WriteLine(dateTime == dateTimeConvertedBack);  //results in false??
}
```

Which prints:

```
12/08/2013 15:43:56
12/08/2013 15:43:56
977
977
False
```

Why aren't these two objects treated as equal?

I'm pretty certain an `==` test on `DateTime` should compare values and not the refs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't the same. Look at `dateTime.Ticks` and `dateTimeConvertedBack.Ticks`.

This will work:

```
DateTime dateTimeConvertedBack = ePoch.AddTicks(timeSpan.Ticks);
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure what value was actually getting compared. I wasn't aware of the `Ticks` field. How could I convert it it to a timestamp and back again so it does compare equal?

Comment: Ah thanks (+1). `timeSpan.Ticks` isn't a unix timestamp though?

Comment: @GP89 Ticks are the underlying timekeeping method, which have a higher precision than just "seconds". You were adding seconds, which are comprised of many ticks, which led to the two `DateTime` objects not being exactly equal.

Comment: The timestamp I used was in seconds, but it was a `double` but I guess `double` doesn't have enough precision to represent single Ticks.